# Uncaught ReferenceError: rootReducer is not defined (React inside laravel)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-redux

So im trying to create a react app inside a laravel api and came across this error on redux.

here's my reducer, what am i missing?

```
# ./reducers.js

import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { reducer as formReducer } from "redux-form";

import {
  errorMessage,
} from "./common";

import {
 testApplication
} from "./test_licenses";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  form: formReducer,
  errorMessage,
  testApplication

});

export default rootReducer;
```

and

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import App from "./components/App";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
  <App />
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: Actual error message]

[image: resources\js\src\components\screens\applications\index.js]

Comment: It looks like the error is in `/resources/js/src/components/screens/applications/index.js` can you share the code in that file?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: You've `const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(logger));` in your `App.js` file but you don't import any "rootReducer" or "logger". Also, what is `Container` component, I don't see that imported or declared. Please include all code as formatted code snippets versus links to images. Images are searchable and links are prone to going stale or worse, removed/broken.

Comment: i tried deleting that line but no luck

Comment: Have you tried clicking the link the stacktrace provides you? It should take you right to the line where the undefined "rootReducer" is occurring.

Comment: that actually solved my problem. thank you, the changes didn't took effect when I deleted the line. I tried rebuilding the project. got no errors

Comment: The `rootReducer` code should be placed in `App.js` or `index.js`, you dont need to add it in reducer file and export it